# Is it necessary to freedom of thought that racist ideas must be tolerated?

Tags: subjectivity, freedom, thought, expressed-opinion

Is it necessary to freedom of *thought* that racist ideas must be tolerated?

Why isn't the paradox of tolerance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance) also biased? In other words, why can't we also claim a paradox of intolerance, where we just flip all the statements in paradox of tolerance? And why is this then meaningful?

I have these arguments against content moderation, but I would still be against unnecessary cruelty etc. due to wanting to distinguish between ideas and actions:

- Everything originates from unique thought, so therefore such thoughts are naturally non-constrained.
- Even if some ideas would be harmful, there cannot be a *general consensus on appropriate emotions*. That is, because no-one can know the "inside head" of someone else. Feeling low in self-esteem is not a problem, since nature does not guarantee some certain level of esteem.
- In a more general sense, all ideas are arbitrary, since they originate from subjects.

Based on this, racist *ideas* cannot be generally non-tolerable, because they're essentially a similar bias as any other idea and their interpretation as emotions is entirely subjective. It's possible of course that racist ideas become false generalizations, but if they're ideas then they should be tolerated on the same grounds as "religious hocus pocus". Therefore one cannot claim that there's bannable speech without being favorable of protecting a particular set of emotions as more valid. One may wish to protect an insulted person, but what about the feelings of the insulters?

I guess there's some level of variability in expression though, but banning "inconvenient opinion" in place of "favorable opinion" is opinion totalitarianism.

Yes, it's possibly an enemy of democratic society, but democracy need not be everyone's preference. And it would be a generalization to claim that it is. In other words, must one tolerate "just another opinion" due to all opinions being biased?

And possibly even more fundamentally, the question is about balancing individual freedom to one's own thoughts vs what someone else perceives as tolerable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139255/discussion-on-question-by-mavavilj-is-it-necessary-to-freedom-of-thought-that-ra).

Comment: Concerning the update. No you don't have to tolerate any opinion whatsoever. The question is just do you want to live in a society where people do that? Like freedom of just about anything beyond the mere physical ability is not a right it's an agreement and if you don't hold your part of it why do you expect others to do?

Comment: @haxor789 Well but to draw an example, why should one not express hate towards a thing that one finds hateful? I mean, it's offensive, but it doesn't change the perception.

Comment: @mavavilj Hatred is simply not a productive emotion. Like it's harmful both to the hater and the subject of the hate. You don't gain freedom from it and you decrease someone else's freedom.

Comment: @haxor789 This is clearly BS, since racist ideology is about privileging e.g. "able-people", beautiful people, people of certain color, people of certain belief, ... OTOH one may argue that anti-racism fits your definition. And then one might again understand why there are two sides to this coin. They are really both and all biases.

Comment: No racist ideology is about the bullshit people make up in order to justify discrimination and privilege which in terms of racism comes down to arguing that other people are of a certain superior/inferior characteristic because of "reasons" that are beyond their self (skin color, country of origin etc). So it's a no win situation as you can't stop being what the racists perceives you to be and as you don't change (because you can't) that makes the racist even more angry at you. Also anti-racism isn't one thing it's easy to be an asshole, to avoid being one takes a lot more effort...

Comment: See 'Paradox of resolving discrimination' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84761/paradox-of-resolving-discrimination/84763#84763 I would look to The Golden Rule & intersubjectivity to understand the moral and practical benefits of treating others as we would wish to be treated - & competition between societies to spread their culture, in memetic selection. See 'Studies exploring the rationale of gender equality' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/studies-exploring-the-rationale-of-gender-equality/90235#90235

Comment: https://conjecturesandrefutations.com/2017/08/20/3359/

Comment: @haxor789 Fair, but I still argue that the same argument works for any other idea. "Anti-racism is just an excuse for justifying oppressing people with racist psychobiology". Therefore all ideas might be equivalent.

Comment: @mavavilj The problem is that you're engaging in racist thinking here. That is you assume that it's an inherent immutable characteristic of the individual, while people opposed to racism more often than not consider it to be a behavior that can be reflected upon, mitigated and finally be overcome. It's not the person that is the problem but their flawed thought process and their unreflected behavior. Which is quite different from the idea that the person is the problem which usually culminates in calls for discrimination, segregation and ultimately extermination.

Comment: @mavavilj Also obviously not all ideas are equivalent... Neither in the sense of being the same nor in the sense of being of the same value.

Comment: @haxor789 Yes. Since persons don't exist, they can't be the problem. We are left with tendencies that can likely be changed, hopefully by the one with the harmful tendencies, using self-reflection. The whole issue disappears.

Comment: @haxor789 "The problem is that you're engaging in racist thinking here.". Possibly, but what makes it so that this cannot be respected as a free expression, even if it's evident that's it's free? I'm still not going to march with posters or something. I'm just expressing what I think. That I had such thoughts is a fact.

Comment: @mavavilj Within the last posts you've engaged multiple times in fallacious reasoning by straw manning other people's position in order to create a false equivalence all in favor of a dangerous ideology. So that's not just a neutral opinion that only concerns yourself. That is a violation of the rules of engagement. Now there is usually some leeway on just being wrong, because everyone is sometimes. But instead of trying to resolve that conflict (by arguments for your position or accepting arguments against it), you're trying to demand a "right to be wrong" not by accident but by intention.

Comment: What about an opinion such that denies e.g. the beauty preference, even if it was well-supported?

Comment: Your beauty preferences are your business, when you're mistreating people because of your beauty preferences or pretend as if your preferences constitute an objective standard then that is no longer just your business. But there's already a chat open for that: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139271/discussion-between-haxor789-and-mavavilj Also that's kind of ignoring the problem sketched in the last comment.

Comment: @haxor789 Ehh, what about drawing personal conclusions about debate that's philosophical (ad hominem)? The question rests on a philosophical basis, not on actions or some particular people. It's only questioning the ideas of right and wrong ideas and the willingness to tolerate free ideas that one may not accept. I'm asking about why racist idea should not be tolerated just like any other "inconvenient" opinion? "Racist idea" is also a pretty broad category. By some def.: racist idea: as any idea that suggests a racial group is superior or inferior to another racial group in any way.

Comment: Yet there is certainly biological science that says that there are differences in reproductive fitness. Is this a racist idea?

Comment: @mavavilj With all due respect you're jumping from point to point without giving any a proper thought, that looks less like a philosophical argument and more like you're trying to "win a debate". Neither are comments intended for that nor is that particularly useful. Also again there's one thing to allow for being wrong and another to want to be wrong despite better knowledge and without any argument in one's defense about a topic that can't really be tolerated because it concerns not just oneself but also other people so would lead to conflict or require compromises.

Comment: @mavavilj Science is descriptive not normative.

Comment: I'm just displaying that 1) there exists racist contexts which are important for science and 2) anti-racism is also a bias, but anti-racists may not hold it as such. In particular, we may consider the *blindspot bias*, which is *assuming that the other camp is more biased than one's own*. Such as, possibly, suggesting that anti-racism is an objective standard. And what the question is about is, whether all opinions are truly equivalent since they're essentially all subjective biases with, possibly, the blindspot bias.

Comment: @haxor789 "racism comes down to arguing that other people are of a certain superior/inferior characteristic because of "reasons" that are beyond their self (skin color, country of origin etc". How do you know that racists don't have racist genetics? Or i.e. that their opinion could be protectable on the same grounds as that of sexual minorities that claim that they have a biological condition. Is it possible that someone would accept "sexual minorities have a biological condition" as true and "racists have a biological condition" as false? (is this biased?)

Comment: Or have you thought that criminalizing racist ideas discriminates those that happen to have them? Or that the non-toleration of racist ideas is not about impartial judgement. But a similar bias.

Comment: @mavavilj 1) Again science is descriptive not normative. Science might look at the data and find patterns but to argue that these patterns should be the guiding principles of a social group is far outside of science. In fact "race" was/is so vaguely defined that biology more or less abandoned that concept in humans and replaced it with the more rigorous term of subspecies (subset of a species), while racists often didn't even got that memo and treat the term as if it means a different species or even a group higher up in the biological taxonomy.

Comment: 2) Again that's not what anti-racism is. And while there are different reasons to address and injustice and not all of them aim to dismantle injustices to begin with, but some just like to tilt the scale another way. That doesn't make a tilted scale a good thing, a normal thing or something that is harmless. Also your sexual orientation is your business and the world isn't effected by that, trying to privilege yourself and disenfranchise others is a very different concept. So accepting one and rejecting the other is not a contradiction you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to have racist ideas and to favor discriminating other people. That is your decision and you've got to live with the consequences of that decision, that's more than you could say about many people on the receiving end of racism, who have no chance to change anything to not be targeted.

Comment: @haxor789 It's not possible to demonstrate such claim. E.g. it's well-known that depression and uncontrolled negative thoughts are connected. **You cannot demonstrate that someone would not have involuntary racist thoughts**. Again I feel that we're talking about a similar issue as demonstrating atypical sexual orientation as chosen or not chosen. And if such racist thoughts would in fact be "involuntary", then is discriminating people holding them ableism, favoritism towards people with no such trait?

Comment: It's also possible to consider it unnormative for some people to ask for respect that they're not voluntarily given. Showing that racist and anti-racist beliefs are both biases. Or, i.e., we can as well claim that nobody is forcing someone to feel bad about themselves. So even if someone feels worthless, then it's their decision. As was written "there's no general consensus on appropriate emotions".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139452/discussion-between-haxor789-and-mavavilj).

Comment: This cannot be opinion-based unless all thoughts are.

Comment: @mavavilj Please use the chat.

Comment: It's also possible to suggest that discrimination is a highly useful phenomenon, if one has fewer discriminable characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik we are not able to read thoughts let alone regulate them (not even for ourselves). So this whole statement is kind of a straw man, as it's not about "thoughts" it's about speech and action following from that. At least that is what the paradox of tolerance is concerned with, so why else would you mention it?

Also obviously the paradox of tolerance is biased in that it asserts that a "liberal, pluralistic society", one in which everyone is able to express themselves, is a good thing. So it rejects ideas of authoritarianism and totalitarianism which would argue that the will of the authority or a certain ideology is to be followed dogmatically.

That's not a some hidden agenda that's the plain and obvious premise. The paradox is whether you should accept people who challenge that very premise. Because if you allow for people to silence others and submit them to their will, then you're freedom to express yourself is gone. However if you overdo it you'll be the one silencing and submitting people to your will. That's the paradox. So despite having the intent to be tolerant you need some intolerance towards the intolerance to enable a tolerant society.

Now intolerance doesn't have that paradox. Intolerance simply doesn't care what other people have to say, what their perspectives are and whether they are able to express themselves and contribute to the public discussion. Intolerance specifically means that you "do not allow/accept" it, so it favors that there is no discussion and that people just take up their place in the Intolerant's master plan. So for the intolerant it might just matter whether they are in power to command others or whether they are subject to someone else who commands them. Silencing and subjugating other's is (to the intolerant) not a contradiction with their goal, it IS the goal.

> Everything originates from unique thought, so therefore such thoughts
> are naturally non-constrained.

That's not really a sound argument. First of all not everything originates from thoughts and thoughts might themselves originate from experience and whatnot. And even if they did why would that mean that they are not constraint?

> Even if some ideas would be harmful, there cannot be a general
> consensus on appropriate emotions.

There can absolutely be a consensus on appropriate emotions, why shouldn't there be one? Whether that's any useful, whether you're able to control your emotions to that extend, whether it's enforceable or whether that's a good idea to begin with. Would all be valid questions about such ideas but that doesn't mean you couldn't do it.

> Feeling low in self-esteem is not a
> problem, since nature does not guarantee some certain level of esteem.

A problem to whom? To you who might not feel that way? Maybe, maybe not. Do you care about that person with low self-esteem and don't like to see them struggle? Then yes it is a problem. If you don't well, that's up to you. But to the person having low self-esteem that most likely is a problem if it means they don't enjoy being themselves. And what does nature have to do with that? Is nature any normative in that sense? People aren't naturally meant to drive, fly have computers or whatnot and we do it anyway, so why should we constrain ourselves to what is natural? It's not like everything there is in nature is by default good, there's death, harm, suffering and whatnot.
There's a limit to that thinking in terms of pissing in the pool that you're swimming in (climate change, pollution, questionable industrial production of food optimized for profit not health, and so on), but that doesn't mean we have to feel bad because it's "natural". On doesn't have to accept a status quo especially not if it isn't working to begin with.

One caveat to the nature of ideas: Sure you might not be able to control the onset of emotions. Like if you're feeling sad, angry, happy or whatnot you're feeling that regardless of whether you want to or not and there's hardly anything you can do about that. But how you deal with those emotions is still at least partially up to you. And you can argue that certain ways of handling them work better or not as good as others.

> In a more general sense, all ideas are arbitrary, since they originate from subjects.

That doesn't make them arbitrary... That just means you have to figure in a lot more individual context than you'd need to if you'd consider them to be subject independent or objective.

> Based on this, racist ideas cannot be generally non-tolerable, because they're essentially a similar bias as any other idea and their interpretation as emotions is entirely subjective.

That depends on how broad you define racism here. Like whether you find someone likeable or abhorrent on first sight and based on a subconscious cocktails of whatnot is an emotion and/or bias. To construct a theoretical and practical ideology and engaging in political action with the goal to privilege your peer-group and/or disenfranchise another "group" (that might just be a group because you said they are), is a little more than a fluke of an emotion...

> It's possible of course that racist ideas become false generalizations, but if they're ideas then they should be tolerated on the same grounds as "religious hocus pocus". Therefore one cannot claim that there's bannable speech without being favorable of protecting a particular set of emotions as more valid.

Why should you tolerate "religious hocus pocus"? I mean that's usually why you have a separation of church and state because you can hardly argue with religious people as their "god said so"-argument works for them and for nobody else, so there's no rational discussion. Which is why you make laws that are not based in religion and make religious people figure out how they can exist within these laws if they want to. Cults are literally one of these totalitarian groups which are intolerant and "unreasonable" as their acting upon axioms that may be false but are unquestionable.

> I guess there's some level of variability in expression though, but
> banning "inconvenient opinion" in place of "favorable opinion" is
> opinion totalitarianism.

It's not about "different" or "inconvenient" opinion it's about the very foundation of a society and the kind of society you want to live in. Again societies are never unbiased and don't claim to. Modern societies explicitly fancy themselves for having equal rights, individual freedom, equality before the law, the ability to go into politics yourself or at least to elect politicians, equal suffrage and so on.

These aren't neutral, but these are fundamental to society as we know it. So if you try to chop away at those by making certain groups of people more privileged than others then you're eroding that very concept of society. It's not that this is a physical force or something that is impossible to do. But if you'd take Kant's perspective of the categorical imperative and envision yourself at the receiving end of such a system that strips people of their rights, freedoms and maybe even their lives then that's certainly not "good".

Also it might not even be all that great if you're not at the receiving end, but that's a different story for a different time.

TL;DR you can't just swap terminology these ideas are based on different premises

Comment: "And even if they did why would that mean that they are not constraint?" Because this is the essence of freedom of thought: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_thought If one has a racist thought and expresses it, then there's ultimately no constraint to this. It just happens and it's individual. Def. of *constraint*: "The threat or use of force to prevent, restrict, or dictate the action or thought of others."

Comment: If we tolerate "religious hocus pocus", then we should tolerate any other belief. Since they're all beliefs. If we don't tolerate, then we have a case of "allowed beliefs".

Comment: "There can absolutely be a consensus on appropriate emotions, why shouldn't there be one?", because self-esteem is not a constant.

Comment: @mavavilj I don't know where this definition of constraint is coming from, a constraint is more or less a "restriction", which can include natural and man made restrictions, including self-imposed restrictions. Or is your argument that you're able to think and express things in the sense of being physically capable of doing so? Well yes. But as soon as other people enter the scene that "freedom" is not an absolute thing but ultimately just an agreement.

Comment: @mavavilj Pretty much all societies have rules, laws and regulations so yes there are "allowed and disallowed believes" it's not that this is a surprising insight, is it? Like you might think murder is fine and the law might disagree with that.

Comment: @mavavilj A consensus on appropriate emotions does not require a self-esteem to be a constant. And neither do you personally have to treat it as a constant to feel it being to low...

Comment: Yes it does, because otherwise you have people complaining that calling them ugly hurts their feelings, but it doesn't hurt the bully's feelings. I.e. self-esteem is not a constant, and there aren't universally shared feelings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139268/discussion-between-haxor789-and-mavavilj).

Comment: "To construct a theoretical and practical ideology and engaging in political action with the goal to privilege your peer-group and/or disenfranchise another "group"". Ehh, this is also what an anti-racist group does. Ultimately I think there's no such thing as being non-biased. There are just biases and people who believe they're not biased, since feeling like being unbiased is itself a bias. https://effectiviology.com/bias-blind-spot/

Comment: The chat is still open why don't you continue there? Also there's some major difference between individual biases and imperfect inequality and deliberate search for and defense of inequality. Is that an example "some people are so accustomed to privilege that equality feels to them like oppression"?

Comment: Anti-racist groups also do the silencing thing (fascism) you're blaming racists for.

Comment: I think "allowed belief" is a fallacy about limiting the freedom of thought. A fallacy of equating threat with capability. Suggesting that communication and "what follows" are intrinsically connected. I think it's perfectly possible to speak racist and bear no connection to physical violence. Just because one'd label person X to be "ugly" or whatever does not imply more than someone expressing that he/she perceives X to be "ugly" (just like we'd say that "this painting is ugly"). Does this now mean that there's necessarily a genocide? What is a subject's right to perception?

Comment: What I find is that some forms against racist thought are in fact against inequal treatment based on real perceived indifference.

Comment: @mavavilj Fascism includes a lot more than just silencing the opposition.

Comment: @mavavilj It's not a fallacy because it's not a general statement. It's a "law" a man made agreement between people, the only thing that could be fallacious about it would be the reasoning that people give for why such a law would be good... And you can theoretically make a convincing case for why an ideology that is hostile cult like, frustrating and furthering hatred will lead to action and you can list an unfortunate lot of these actions as evidence, what do you have beyond your gut feeling? If you were serious it would be in your interest to bring forth more than that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @mavavilj Also genoicides don't start with genocides either and alienation, othering, scapegoating, hatred, stereotyping are all things that are precursors to genocide because they lay the groundwork for people to accept the unacceptable. Also again telling someone else they are ugly is not just your personal preference you're actively a dick to another person. Also a painting is an object and a person is a subject... And you could just as well say "it's not my taste" and express your sentiment adequately unless it actually is your intention to make a generalized statement ...

Comment: Someone could claim it's hurtful to say that someone's painting is ugly. But if one'd think freely and then say "you're ugly", then ...? No, they're **similar perceptions** (of aesthetics), but some people may not accept opinions that are not of their taste, because they too understand that ugly may mean bad.

Comment: @mavavilj There is a major difference between "I think it is ..." and "**it is**..." one is an expression of an opinion the other is claiming a fact. Your opinion is largely your business, facts usually also involve other people. There are more likely than not syntactic exceptions where you express facts with "I think..." and opinions with "it is... " but the overall concept is not that hard to grasp that one is a 1/8billion opinions that you don't have to give a shit about and the other is a claim that of a universal/objective truth that is not supposed to be contradicted.

Comment: @mavavilj Don't like that picture? Then don't look at it. If you think it's constructive criticism that you don't like it and what you don't like about it, share that with the artist, if you think it's nothing but hurtful and you don't care enough to argue about it keep it to yourself. But regardless of what you think or even if that picture is objectively butt ugly, that does not allow for you to make claims of superiority or inferiority for the artist because of their art. They are still an equal human being with all rights that this entails and bad art is no reason to take that away.

Comment: Then explain why "only certain opinions are tolerable" is not "I think it is ...". And why, based on this, we should not tolerate all sorts of "I think it is ...". Freedom of thought is naturally *non-constrained*, since there's nothing but some storybook machine that may manipulate my thought content. Therefore freedom of thought and speech is, in fact, "It is". Ultimately I think all opinions are "I think it is".

Comment: @mavavilj 'Then explain why "only certain opinions are tolerable" is not "I think it is ..."' With all due respect but if that question is legit, you should really take a step back and contemplate. Like the painfully obvious answer is that it doesn't start with "I think..." but even beyond that you should be able to realize that this is not an opinion but the claim of a universal fact? Right?

Comment: It's still an opinion and "I think ...". There's no real universality. So what's wrong with "I think all X are ugly"? Prejudical maybe, but is this a free opinion? **Yes.** I still think that suggesting that there exists bannable speech is nothing more than opinion totalitarianism and in fact the intolerance of opinions that one doesn't agree with. And tying this to other forms of harm is prone to slippery slope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139505/discussion-between-haxor789-and-mavavilj).

Answer (score 2):

In a libertarian view, thought remains free whether or not the eventual articulation of those thoughts is tolerated.

Whilst the anticipation of intolerance might influence a person's thoughts, there is no external agent policing the thinker until the thought is expressed.

A person might experience a thought which if publicised would be considered taboo, but this taboo does not prevent the thought; it merely provides consequences for any expression of the thought.

These consequences might complicate, temper or encourage the thinker's thought processes, but until 'thought police' eventuate, we are free (barring determinism) to think as we wish, regardless of how our ideas are tolerated by any community in which we live.

Mind you, 'barring determinism' asks that we ignore the way prior events (including external pressures such as taboos) manifest even in our thoughts. If determinism or randomness is true, it is likely pointless to consider questions such us this without allowing for the fact that our thoughts might in fact never be free; that they are always the consequence of forces beyond our control, including the forces present in environmental factors such as tolerance and intolerance.

Comment: If a person expects 'that someone tolerate racist speech', it may be because they are a) racist and/or b) believe in an absolutish freedom of speech. As for your fat/thin example, you are free to value thinness more than fatness if you wish, regardless of how tolerated such a view might be by others. Once you articulate this idea, you may be required to defend this stance against people who disagree.

Comment: And if a person expects 'that someone tolerate anti-racist speech'? "Once you articulate this idea, you may be required to defend this stance against people who disagree.". Again, this is not a problem, debate is not a problem. The problem is when a particular form of speech is criminalized. While others are not.

Comment: You might find this [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/freedom-speech/) entry worthwhile. It includes sections on hate speech, the Harm Principle, the Offence Principle, and free speech in democracy.

Comment: Fair, but there's no objective standard.

Comment: Also, why can't we accept intolerance as a real feature? As part of true freedom. Why isn't a restriction on it itself intolerance?

Comment: What do you mean by 'real feature'?

Comment: That it's a feature of human communication for some that should be viewed as normal. It's true that e.g. "whites are better than blacks" is not generally true, but it doesn't mean that one couldn't hold the view that "whites look more beautiful than blacks".

Comment: There's nothing I read in the Paradox of Intolerance that states that intolerance is abnormal. On the contrary, it implies tolerance is normal, hence the claim that 'society must retain the right to be intolerant of intolerance'.

Comment: Yes and this I don't agree with, because I have different ideas. And so have some other people. And I find that suggesting that I agree with PoT is opinion dictating. My belief is not the kind that PoT posits. If there's a law that says my belief is PoT, then it's still really not. In other words, I'm asking for a right to hold *my views*, not someone else's. Also, I don't consider "society" to change this in any way. I believe in anarchist conception of freedom which is that informed people are just fine without any dictating.

Comment: In a broader sense PoT can also be interpreted to be left-wing propaganda, which is that it's not really "true" except for those with this leftist bias, even if it's posited as a generally true fact. In another interpretation, PoT perhaps posits that without equality law the minorities would be very much in danger. Which is itself okay, but it still doesn't mean that everyone needs to agree on this belief. I mean, I cannot explain why I feel aversion towards some types of people, but I do.

Comment: The argument is that why can't people allow people like that to be like they are. As long as they don't hurt anyone physically? I mean, in a different perspective, why isn't right to a racist psychobiology similar to a right to sexual orientation? The article on lookism suggests very much that to perceive people differently is a built-in thing. In this case we could use the same "born this way" argument.

Comment: Because racists do hurt other people. You can't deny someone else equal rights and dignity and claim you're not being hurtful towards them. Like if I claim you're a lesser human being and your arguments are worthless because of that, how do you expect us to have a conversation or even a coexistence? Like whatever you say you can only lose because to me you'd lose by default. That shit is bound to lead to aggression...

Comment: Or then it's just about emotions which I argued as being out of scope, since there doesn't exist a right way to feel. I can agree on same rights, but I don't agree that I need to change my free beliefs or free expressions. Or otherwise they would not be free. They're just different opinions. I can also claim that anti-racists hurt my feelings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139271/discussion-between-haxor789-and-mavavilj).

Answer (score 2):

Well Britain has a free press and is a free liberal democracy but if you started shouting racist sterotypes like n***** or w** on the streets you'd be arrested for spreading hate speech.

So that is one answer: what is the laws in the country in which you are speaking which regulate what can be said in what context.

But perhaps you are talking about social media and the internet? Well in that case, and in my opinion, it should be the publishing laws of the countries involved - both hosting and where the material is published - which means everywhere - that should regulate that particular world. This will be expensive. Luckily for social media they managed to gut that particular possibility when a piece of US legislation ruled that internet publishers were third party hosts rather than publishets.

I see this as a lamentably short-sighted piece of legislation. But I expect this to change in future when it is understood that social media companies cannot be trusted to moderate their own activities as the evidence of Facebook Whistleblower, Frances Haugen, who worked in Facebook's Civic Integrity team, before Congress showed so amply. Essentially, the social media companies have coerced private individuals to police their products for free whilst raking in billions of profit. This is where they are making their billions. If they had to cost in the costs of moderation and policing then their profit margins would dramtically fall.

They have, as has happened with Big Tobacco and Big Oil, socialised costs whilst privatising profits. It's a profitable racket - which is whilst they're still at it - you might say it is one of Capitalism's original sins.

This 'coercion' is slavery by a new name. Both the UK & the USA have legislation on modern forms of slavery. It's perhaps not at all surprising that the nation that has most profitted from the transatlantic slave trade has invented a new form. This is another original sin of Capitalism.

For example, one commentator at a well-respected institution states that digital slavery has aspects of both chattel and modern slavery and the trade is npt being enabled - as it was in the 18th C - by sailing ships, guns, whips and chains - but this time by an unholy triumvirate of surveillance technology, personal data trafficking and AI.

He (I'm assuming it is a he) explains that the trafficking of personal data should not be seen as simply a question of privacy as it was seen in the daus of the early internet but in todays surveillance society it should be also understood the *control* of people. And mental control is mental slavery and ergo slavery...

This I think is grounds for a class-action suit. It merely requires a civil liberties law firm taking out some newspaper adverts requesting people who feel that they have been "digitally enslaved" to come forward in all confidentiallity so a casebook of evidence of wrong-doing can be built up.

Answer (score 2):

The core (generally unrecognized) problem here is that public speech has **two** components:

- The semantic element, comprised of the production, expression, and elaboration of meaning (thoughts and ideas), and...
- The syntactic element, comprised of the rules of proper communication, without which communication is ultimately impossible.

A Liberal society must necessarily be tolerant of racist thoughts and racist expressions (the semantic element), but must necessarily be intolerant of any expression which violates the rules (syntax) of communication. Liberal society *depends* on the rules of communication to eventually resolve disagreements, so activities and expressions which result in the suppression, denigration, or dismissal of proper communication cannot be tolerated without destroying the fabric of Liberal society.

Put bluntly, one *might* talk about the inferiority of a particular group as a political position; that's a theoretically acceptable matter of semantics. But one *must* talk about such in a way that includes that group in the conversation meaningfully, not rejecting, dismissing, or oppressing their views on the matter. The paradox isn't a paradox of liberalism; it is a paradox of bigotry, that the bigot must communicate his bigotry in a way which does not presume the bigotry as true.

Those who have been paying attention are aware that most of the current kerfuffles about 'free speech' are in fact arguments that one should be allowed to insult, degrade, defame, and/or abuse disliked people or groups. They are explicitly arguments that attack the rules of proper communication, offered to allow forms of expression that preclude or suppress certain viewpoints from being offered publicly. That is strictly and stridently illiberal. Even the most intolerant bigot can express his views in ways that allow for proper communication and discussion, but doing so is often antithetical to the goal of bigotry since it assumes that the target of bigotry is necessarily an equal in the discussion. Liberal society does not need to suppress the vies of such people; it merely needs to prevent such people from suppressing the free expression of others in society. It must guard the *syntax* of communicative spaces and allow the *semantics* to play out as they will.

Comment: Liberal societies work, others self-destruct. It seems like a pretty simple lesson.

Comment: You make a good point concerning the ideas being expressed and the way in which they are expressed. But I'm slightly skeptical as to whether "syntax" is the correct word for what you're describing. From what I know and can find syntax is really more about form, grammar, structure of a sentences and so on. So I'd be less concerned about a dyslexic person violating syntax than about one arguing that other people's opinions are invalid because they are inferior.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Liberal society gave us colonialism, fascism, and Trumpism. Most modern tyrants get themselves elected to power by easily manipulated masses. Your 'lesson' isn't 'simple'; it's facile.

Comment: @haxor789: yeah, I know, I'm extending the use of the term 'syntax' in weird ways, because there isn't really a good term for what I mean. Basically I mean this: just like there are rules of sentence construction, there are rules of conversation construction. Break either set of rules and you end up with gibberish, though the latter is harder to see.

Comment: Our answers agree following different lines of thought.

Comment: Ok, so how about: some types of societies necessarily fail. If one wishes to prevent failure, those should be avoided. Better a chance of hard-fought for success than certain disaster. I was tempted to give a "no true society..." argument, but that never goes over very well in SE. It is deflating when I try to make a sincere point and someone attacks my definitions.

Comment: @TedWrigley The problem with gibberish is that you don't understand each other and thus are incapable of communicating, but breaking the rules of communication could still be understood, though it would also break the rules of communication and thus ... yeah be similar in that it renders you incapable of communicating. So yes, but it still feels weird.

Comment: @TedWrigley Is it fair to say that they are the offspring of the liberal society? Like colonialism is much older and fascism and Trumpism explicitly reference an earlier less liberal time as their ideal. And most tyrants do not have a democratic mandate and neither had Trump. Also facile is just Italian or French for easy. The problem is more or less the paradox of tolerance in that the the pluralism routinely extends to movements that want to do away with it and explicitly contradict the very premise of a liberal society. So did they produce it or just not prevent it/oppose it enough?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it necessary to freedom of thought that racist ideas must be tolerated?**

Concerning the place of racism in one’s thinking, I think it is wise to take a cue from Robin DiAngelo, who wrote *White Fragility*. Here is the personal goal: there exists no evidence in relation to which one’s thinking is fragile. In short, there are no “no-go” zones in thinking, so long as the evidence is present. “Fragility” means (to me, at any rate) that there is a set of issues that one just does not think about; a person’s mind shuts down before there is any risk of having to question this set of beliefs. In the absence of fragility in one’s thinking, one’s thought is truly free.

To achieve such a goal, a person cannot tolerate racist ideas even in his or her personal thinking, because to entertain such notions would be to introduce one brand of fragility into that person’s thought. This technique also seems to avoid the paradox of tolerance, given that all challenges to thinking are accepted, but must be evidence-based.

Comment: This sounds biased, because it's certain that racist ideas exist. What about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denialism

Comment: "This technique also seems to avoid the paradox of tolerance, given that all challenges to thinking are accepted, but must be evidence-based." How exactly does that work?

Comment: Also I think some racist ideas are highly evidence-based. Such as preference for beauty.

Comment: @mavavilj. The cite to Denialism answer the first comment adequately. On that page there is a picture of a sign: “Denied facts are still facts.” Race is a social construct. Racist ideas to the contrary certainly exist, but are merely examples of Denialism.

Comment: @mavavilj. As for the “preference for beauty” comment, that is more a part of David Hume’s is-ought problem. As such, it calls for a more detailed treatment than I can offer here.

Comment: @haxor789. The perpetual call for evidence places its own check, or brake, against the toleration of everything. The question of the effect of tolerance need not arise.

Comment: @MarkAndrews Ok so you're the tolerance is also only temporarily as long as there are not sufficient evidence against something?

Comment: @haxor789. There must be affirmative evidence to support a conclusion that a belief is true.  An absence of evidence that something is false is not the standard.

Comment: @MarkAndrews That sounds like it's more substantiated but wasn't that the problem with positivism that you can come up with lots of supporting evidence but that this doesn't mean much as long as they aren't conclusive?

Comment: @haxor789. I don’t know enough about positivism to answer.

Comment: @mavavilj. I think this comment is intended for the answer posted by haxor789.

Answer (score 1):

The paradox is this: I am tolerant to all ideas as a matter of principle, including ideas which are specifically opposed to the idea of tolerance itself. Thus tolerance is undermined in itself, leading to intolerance.

The resolution to the paradox, in my opinion, is that the ideal of tolerance, freedom and openness itself should be accepted first and foremost in order for the paradox to lose its appeal.

Specifically, a racist, for example, can express his racist views freely, only as long as he accepts the same right and existence of the opposite ideas on an equal footing.

A similar view has been expressed by [Jainists in the multi-sided reality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism#Many-sided_reality_(anek%C4%81ntav%C4%81da)) which itself stems from [basic respect for beings and non-violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jainism#Non-violence_(ahimsa))

If this does not hold, **then tolerance is under no obligation to accommodate the racist in expressing such views**. **Because the principle itself that would make this possible is not accepted**.

A somewhat similar ["paradox" appears for democracy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91585/are-protests-in-a-democracy-ethical/91591#91591), in that some people may use the rights democracy grants them, in order to abolish those very rights (for others). One can argue that in that case democracy is abolished as a result. But by default limiting those rights to avoid this, is also abolishing democracy. So what to do?

Again the resolution, in my opinion, is that the framework, the principle is accepted and respected first by everyone involved, thus itself is under no attack.

Can this be enforced? For better or for worse, no. It has to be consciously and willingly accepted as the best alternative against others. And it can be argued, that indeed it is the best alternative.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139659/discussion-on-answer-by-nikos-m-is-it-necessary-to-freedom-of-thought-that-raci).